# Wireless scanning with FUJITSU Document Scanner ScanSnap iX500 on Linux

Tags: wifi, scanner

The FUJITSU Document Scanner ScanSnap iX500 supports wireless scanning on Mac and PC. Does anyone know how to set that up on Linux? I'm running Arch / KDE and I use XSane for scanning.

Comment: Have you installed the driver yet?

Comment: No. Where do I find a linux driver for this scanner? (It works via USB without any drivers. I just use XSane.)